# How can i find the computer type in Linux using Java?

Tags: java, linux

How can i find the computer type in Linux using Java ?
I need to find out if the device is a laptop/desktop/server/virtual machine.

I managed to find out if the computer is a virtual machine if it is VMWare.

```
Process virtual = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo dmidecode -s system-manufacturer");
                BufferedReader virmar = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(virtual.getInputStream()));
                String s11;
                while ((s11 = virmar.readLine()) != null) {
                    virtualm = s11;
                    vmName = virtualm; 
                    if (s11.contains("VMware")) {
                        virtualma = "1";
                    } else {
                        virtualma = "";
                    }
            }
```

Comment: What is your criteria to distinguish between laptop, server and desktop?

Comment: maybe a dumb question but why would you want to make this distinction? I'm really curious.

Comment: Does `cat /proc/cpuinfo` provide you with what you need?

Comment: What do you mean by "computer type"?

Comment: @Neagu V for what reason do you need this info? what changes in your application you are gonna do on a base of this info?

Comment: This is not a Java question, it's entirely operating system dependent, so in this case it's a Linux question.

Comment: I just need to send on a POST some information about the linux system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I develop an inventory software and i need to know the workstation type.
I managed to solve this using:

```
            String[] type = {"Laptop", "Notebook", "Portable", "Sub Notebook"};

            ....

            String cmd1[] = {"/bin/sh","-c","lsb_release -a | grep -i Description"};
            Runtime runsv = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process prsv = runsv.exec(cmd1);
            BufferedReader sv = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    prsv.getInputStream()));
            String line1;
            while ((line1 = sv.readLine()) != null) {
                server = line1;

            }

            String cmd = "sudo dmidecode --string chassis-type";
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
            BufferedReader comt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    pr.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = comt.readLine()) != null) {
                getcomputerType = line;
            }
            if (getcomputerType.equals(type)) {
                compType = "2";
            } else {
                if (server.equals("Server")) {
                compType = "3";
                }
                else{
                    compType = "1";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

dmidecode has `chassis-type` to specify this information:

```
sudo dmidecode --string chassis-type
```

On the two systems I have it returns `Mini Tower` and `Space-saving`.

Microsoft [documents the known chassis types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156537.aspx).